# Why do I get 404 with a valid url using Net::HTTP.post_form?

Tags: ruby, post, http-status-code-404, net-http

I use the following code to pass data into a website:

```
require "net/http"
params = {"message"=>"some message", "to"=>"someone"}
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://example.com/m/send"),params)
```

When I inspect the web page, the form action is `http://example.com/m/send` and I can post the data using the site itself without any problem.

I keep getting `HTTP 404` and my data is not passed to the database.

When I request the page with `GET` method, then I get `HTTP 405`, which is an unauthorized request error. This guarantees that the page exists.

Since the url is valid, what would prevent the data being posted? And how can I fix that?

Comment: The target form may require data in cookies. Are you the owner of the target site ?

Comment: Nope, I am not. If it is like that how can I workaround this problem?

Comment: "If it is like that how can I workaround this problem?", the easiest answer is to use the Mechanize gem. It tracks cookies for you and will resubmit them as needed.

Comment: I disagree with the `HTTP 405` being a guarantee the page exists. One could want to authorize requests before checking the resource exists, to prevent blind probing.

Comment: OK but it exists believe me. Otherwise why would the action attribute be "/m/send"?

Comment: Go on the form page with your navigator, clear the cookies of your navigator, and validate the form. If it fails, your problem is related to cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the question using Net/HTTP library solely; however, Mechanize gem as Tin Man suggested in the comments solves the problem and successfully posts the data into the server.

It is also more flexible and easier in terms of following redirection. Hence, if anyone runs into this problem like I did, I recommend them using the Mechanize gem.